# Change Customer Login Password in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to Change Login Password of a customer in `Magento`, I Uses the below Code to Update the Password But It doesn't work for me

```
 $customerid = 46;
 $oldpassword = 12345678;
 $newpassword = 87654321;
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerid);
 $passwordhash = $customer['password_hash'];
 $phasharray = explode(":",$passwordhash);
 $passpostfix = $phasharray[1];
 $completeOldPassword =  $oldpassword.":".$passpostfix;
 if($completeOldPassword==$passwordhash){
    $customer->setPassword($newpassword);
    $customer->save();
 }
```

Comment: Why this: $passwordhash = $customer['password_hash'];
 $phasharray = explode(":",$passwordhash);
 $passpostfix = $phasharray[1];
 $completeOldPassword =  $oldpassword.":".$passpostfix;
 if($completeOldPassword==$passwordhash){

Comment: I found this on http://ajaditya.blogspot.in/2013/03/change-customer-password-magento.html URL to change password that is why i use this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use below code to update user's password, you need username and storeid additional variable to update. :-

```
$validate = 0; $result = '';
$customerid = 46;
$username = 'YOUR_USERNAME';
$oldpassword = 12345678;
$newpassword = 87654321;
$storeid = 'YOUR_STORE_ID';

$websiteId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeid)->getWebsiteId();
try {
     $login_customer_result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->authenticate($username, $oldpassword);
     $validate = 1;
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
     $validate = 0;
}
if($validate == 1) {
     try {
          $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerid);
          $customer->setPassword($newpassword);
          $customer->save();
          $result = 'Your Password has been Changed Successfully';
     }
     catch(Exception $ex) {
          $result = 'Error : '.$ex->getMessage();
     }
}
else {
     $result = 'Incorrect Old Password.';
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: how to customerid , usrname,oldpassword, and newpassword dynamically Please update answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224010/changepasswordaction-action-in-magento-1-9-3-8

Answer (score 3):

If you echo $completeOldPassword and $passwordhash you see they can't match because your $oldpassword is supposed to be a password hash with salt. Now it's just plaintext

If you only want to change the password without checking old password  try this

```
$customerid = 46;
$newpassword = 87654321;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerid);
$customer->setPassword($newpassword);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: If you need to verify take a look at Mage_Core_Model_Encryption it has verifyHash function

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is Using forget password and reset it with email account.Magento add security salt hashes in password and you can't change it like that you'r doing.

Answer (score 0):

To allow change password for customer.update API request

Use password_hash as the attribute name  to send the request,
and in **update** function of
$MAGENTO_ROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php add

> if(strlen($customerData["password_hash"]) > 5){
>
> $customer->setPassword($customerData["password_hash"]);
>
> }

before $customer->save();

Forget the password attribute mentioned in http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.update.html

only password_hash is a valid attribute for customer entity.